# List out enabled users who are members of certain security groups

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a list of all enabled users in a particular Security group. Seems simple but i cannot manage to get the correct output.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Active Directory:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "PUT_HERE_ADGROUP_NAME" -Recursive | Get-ADUser | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $True} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

If you want to see local users use `Get-LocalGroupMember` and `Get-LocalUser` with same filter

Comment: Nice. Note that `Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $True}` can be simplified to `Where-Object { $_.Enabled }` and even `Where-Object Enabled`